# Printing of HTML markup with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, printing, mfc

I was curious if I can embed printing of HTML markup in my C++ application? Here's what I need:

1. Ability to specify which printer to print to.
2. Ability to change paper size.
3. Ability to specify margins/gutter, etc.
4. Ability to let end-user preview the result.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to **virtually print** the HTML page to a PDF file using [wkHTMLtoPDF C++ Library](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), and then print it.

Pros:

- It allows you to keep a draft copy for future use.

Cons:

- It's not a *print-HTML-directly* library

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this library: http://www.terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/ . It does everything you need, assuming you want to print the *rendered* html, and not syntax-highlighted html source code, which is not entirely clear from your question - but

Answer (score 1):

MFC has a CHtmlView class that is part of their Document/View architecture.  Hence, you can create a rather simple MDI "Web Browser" in MFC pretty easily.

Comment: Yes I can but how do I print from it?

Comment: If you run the MFC Application Wizard, there should be checkbox for choosing "Printing and Print Preview" support under the "Advanced" settings.